# How to recognize where from component is invoked to display proper text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like to reuse component which is `uploading/adding` products to the database,
sometimes product is type of *finished product*, and sometimes the product is part of  *unfinished product*.

```
http://localhost:1000/finished-product/add

http://localhost:1000/unfinished-product/add
```

In my routes I've defined:

```
 <Route exact path="/finished-product/add" component={AddProduct} />

 <Route exact path="/unfinished-product/add" component={AddProduct} />
```

When my component `AddProduct` is loaded I would like to display proper text for example:

*Please add unfinished product* : or *Please add finished product* :

I just want to separate those texts and stuffs like that, so how could I recognize if I'm displaying component

from `path="/unfinished-product/add"` or from  `path="/finished-product/add"`.

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Route props**

As your component is rendered by a `Route` it gets the following prop :

```
this.props.location.pathname // => '/finished-product/add' || '/unfinished-product/add'
```

You can use it to write a condition.

```
const text = this.props.location.pathname === '/finished-product/add' ? 'Please add finished product' : 'Please add unfinished product';
```

References:

Route props: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

`location` prop: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

**Or use `render` function with a new prop**

Another solution would be using `render` function in your routes passing a new prop to your component :

```
<Route exact path="/finished-product/add" render={routeProps => <AddProduct {...routeProps} finished />} />
<Route exact path="/unfinished-product/add" render={routeProps => <AddProduct {...routeProps} />} />
```

So then you have a `finished` boolean prop in your `AddProduct` component.

```
const text = this.props.finished ? 'Please add finished product' : 'Please add unfinished product';
```

Reference:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using query params `/product/add?status='finished'`
while defining routes,

```
<Route exact path="/product/add" component={AddProduct} />
```

and in component,

```
<Link to='/product/add?status="finished"'>Finished Product</Link>
<Link to='/product/add?status="unfinished"'>Unfinished Product</Link>
```